# How use scalene for memory profiling in a django app

Tags: python, django, code-profiling, scalene

I am trying to find memory leak inside my django app but couldn't find a way in official docs of scalene or somewhere else about how can i use it with django.

so far i have tried running runserver command like below

```
$ scalene manage.py runserver
```

and after that when i execute my regular view ( which i want to profile ). nothing happens.
when i press `ctrl + c` it stops the runserver command & created a file `profile.html` ( around 25 MB size )

i open that file in chrome but it shows some benchmarks ( like expected ) but nowhere i saw my django view code which i want to profile.

I just tried searching every where but couldn't find a way.

Comment: is something wrong with this question..? I just don't how to make scalene work with django.. and so i did asked but there is no help here.

Comment: did you see https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene/issues/178?  maybe you use the `@profile` decorator to target the code you care about?